# I am getting an error when I try to use a setter. The error message is AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'setter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

class Employee:

```
raise_amt = 1.04

def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last

    self.pay = pay

def fullname(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

@property
def email(self):
    return '{}.{}@email.com'.format(self.first, self.last)

@fullname.setter
def fullname(self,name):
    first,last=name.split(" ")
    self.first=first
    self.last=last
```

emp_1=Employee("Joey","Lang",10000)
emp_1.fullname="Aditya Kumar"
print(emp_1.first)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not defined a `fullname` property to associate with the `fullname` setter.  Adding the `property` decorator to your initial `fullname` method definition should to the trick:

```
@property
def fullname(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)
```